# VHDL set port range with a condition

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, is it possible to set the range of a port using a condition which depends on a generic parameter? For example similar to this:

```
entity example is
    generic (
        IP_VERSION  : integer := 4
    );
    port (
        ip_address  : in std_logic_vector((127 when IP_VERSION = 6 else 31) downto 0)
    );
end example;
```

Comment: VHDL-2019 should support that just fine - My read says it requires the parentheses you included.   If it does not work with your simulator/synthesis tool be sure to file a bug report - unfortunately that is how we tell vendors we want them to support the standard.   OTOH, I think @Tricky answer is the better solution as it is likely you will use this more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible as you have written, even with VHDL 2019 IIRC (when it sees some actual support).

The way to deal with this in all versions of VHDL is to write a function that is available in a package that returns the port size based on the input. for example:

```vhdl
package body example_pkg is
  function get_ip_addr_size (version : natural) return natural is
  begin
    case version is
      when 4 => return 32;
      when 6 => return 128;
      when others => report "Specified IP version (" & to_string(version) & ") is not valid" severity failure;  return 0;
    end case;
  end function;
end package body;


...

use work.example_pkg.all;


entity example is
    generic (
        IP_VERSION  : integer := 4
    );
    port (
        ip_address  : in std_logic_vector(get_ip_addr_size(IP_VERSION)-1 downto 0)
    );
end example;
```

Comment: VHDL-2019 has conditional expressions which are allowed in this context if they have parentheses.